# How to enable batch contextual actions in a ListView?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to follow the official Android guide for [CABforListView](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#CABforListView) very closely, but I have not been able to activate context action view on my ListView item long press.

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        loadList(); // loads Cursor data and sets list adapter in AsyncTask
        ListView listView = getListView();
        listView.setLongClickable(true); // no effect
        listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
        listView.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new AbsListView.MultiChoiceModeListener() {
            // implemention of MultiChoiceModeListener
        });
    }

    // rest of the class
}
```

The following is my list_row_item.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:longClickable="true"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/reminder_row_description"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/reminder_row_interval"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/reminder_row_description"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <Switch
        android:id="@+id/switch_reminder_row"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/reminder_row_interval"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/reminder_row_time"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/reminder_row_interval"
        android:layout_below="@+id/reminder_row_interval"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And my activity_main.xml:

```
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

</ListView>
```

I have tried using `listView.setOnItemLongClickListener()` to start ActionMode manually, but while that has launched contextual action mode I was not able to do multiple selects, and no tutorial/guide has ever needed to do this. I am missing something.

Basically, I want to achieve exactly this effect as seen in Jelly Bean's alarm clock:

[image: Jelly Bean Alarm Clock ListView]

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: How does your `MultiChoiceModeListener` looks like?

Comment: hardly much for now. `onCreateActionMode` inflates the context menu. `onActionItemClicked` is set to do nothing. `onItemCheckedStateChanged` basically has a sanity check that sets the title. but none of these happens. Debugger proves that it is not called at all.

Comment: I'm using a SimpleCursorAdapter for the list adapter. Could this be the problem? Perhaps I would need to manually do my own action mode.

Comment: I hope you're returning `true` from `onCreateActionMode()`.

Comment: FWIW, here is another sample implementation of a multiple-choice action mode: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ActionMode/ActionModeMC

Comment: Thanks @Luksprog for pointing out, that solved my problem! cheers! :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Luksprog comment, returning true from onCreateActionMode() will fix your problem